# Selenium Negative Test Cases to execute in "for" loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want the "for" loop to keep executing even after the error occurs in Selenium java using negative test cases in an "if" "else"if-else statement. Some examples would really be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try Catch` inside for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
try{    

//your goes code here  

}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Exception thrown "+e);
}
}
```